# JMeter - unable to scale network bandwidth using CIFS Sampler(Groovy)

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jcifs

Team,

I'm successful in writing the CIFS JSR223 Sampler(Groovy) using JCIFS. But the problem is I'm not seeing good network throughput by increasing the user. I tried distributed testing, changed buffer size (jcifs property send/receive)..but no luck.

Any help is highly appreciated...here is my code for write and read using Jcifs.

Code for CIFS_Write

```
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
import java.net.InetAddress;
//import java.io.file;
import org.apache.commons.net.io.Util;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFileOutputStream;
//jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.ssnLimit", "1" ); 
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.rcv_buf_size", "223288");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.snd_buf_size", "23288");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.maxBuffers", "50");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.tcpNoDelay", "true");
String user = "xx";
String pass ="xx";
SmbFileOutputStream out = null;
String clientIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
String sharepath =vars.get("sharename")+"server25/"+clientIP+"a1.csv";  
SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile (sharepath, auth);
os = (SmbFileOutputStream)remoteFile.getOutputStream();
InputStream iss = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/mnt/client.csv/"));
//InputStream iss = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream("/opt/client.csv"));
Util.copyStream(iss,os,65535);

    os.close();
    iss.close();
```

Code for CIFS_Read:

```
import jcifs.smb.NtlmPasswordAuthentication;
import jcifs.smb.SmbFile;
//jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.ssnLimit", "1" ); 

String user = "xx";
String pass ="xx";
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.rcv_buf_size", "223288");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.snd_buf_size", "23288");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.maxBuffers", "50");
jcifs.Config.setProperty("jcifs.smb.client.tcpNoDelay", "true");

NtlmPasswordAuthentication auth = new NtlmPasswordAuthentication("",user, pass);
String clientIP = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
String sharepath =vars.get("sharename")+"server25/"+clientIP+"a1.csv";  
SmbFile remoteFile = new SmbFile (sharepath, auth);
InputStream iss = new BufferedInputStream(remoteFile.getInputStream());
byte [] buffer = new byte[65535];
while ((ch = iss.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    continue;
}
iss.close();
```

Answer (score 1):

I understand, you are trying to increase the load by increasing the number of users accessing those code paths.

`JCIFS` maintains a map from Session (think users) -> Transport (think socket to the file server). By default, it assigns `250` sessions per socket, which is probably an overkill and may overwhelm your socket with the traffic.

You should try setting this `JVM property : -Djcifs.smb.client.ssnLimit` and set it to a lower value, such as `5`.